# <select> not populating, buttons inline with <select>

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with html, php and bootstrap to create some lists and buttons. My first questions is that I have written a script populate a "select" drop down list. It should go to the "sounds/" directory and populate itself with .wav files. The "select" shows up properly, it just doesn't populate the list. I do have .wav files in the directory and I gave full permissions to the directory itself. So its not that.

My other question is how would I put a button inline with the the "select" drop down. I don't want on the next line down.

```
<!--CALL TAB-->
<div id="call">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="hero-unit">
      <h5>Call Functions -</h5>
      <h6>Test Paragraph</h6>

      <br>

      <h6> Select a Sound One -</h6>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">
          <select id="sound1">
            <?php 
              foreach(glob('sounds/*.wav') as $filename){
              $rest = substr($filename, 7);    
              echo "<option>".$rest."</option>";
              }
            ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br>

      <h6> Select a Sound Two -</h6>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">
          <select id="sound2"> 
            <?php 
              foreach(glob('sounds/*.wav') as $filename){
              $rest = substr($filename, 7);    
              echo "<option>".$rest."</option>";
              }
            ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br>

      <h6>Volume - </h6>
      <div id="slider-range-max">
      </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6">
        <br>
        <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="index.html">Play <i class="icon-   play"></i></a> <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" href="index.html">Pause <i class="icon-pause"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

    <footer>
      <p>&copy; FOOTER</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to `echo` just `$filename` without `substr()`?

Comment: Just tried, it didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the button next to the select is simple. If you're not styling the `select` or `button` to be a `block` element, then they should appear next to each other (inline block). If the HTML below doesn't work for you (button is not next to select), then try adding `float: left;` to both the `select` and `button`.

For your `glob()`, are you sure the path is correct? Where is the PHP file that's executing this versus the `sounds` folder? What's your directory structure?

http://jsfiddle.net/3JQeZ/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
        <select id="sound1">
            <option>1 option</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the buttons. The "sounds" folder is inside my webroot folder. As for the php file I was unaware that I had to create a separate file. (I'm kind of new to this) I though I could just call a php function directly from the html.

Comment: Well, you can if your server is configured to execute PHP in .html files. If you `echo $filename` do you see anything in the source code? You should. If not, then the problem is with the path. What are the specific folders that your files are in?

Comment: It looks like I misspelled "sounds" on one of those folders. It seems to be working now.